# MySQL Select with Aggregate Functions

Tags: mysql

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT 
      score,subject_name 
 FROM exams_scores,subjects 
WHERE (admission_no = 2771) AND(subjects.subject_code = exams_scores.subject_code)
```

That gives me: all 5 records as expected.
If I do:

```
SELECT 
      score,
      subject_name,
      SUM (score) as TOTAL 
FROM exams_scores,subjects
WHERE (admission_no = 2771) AND (subjects.subject_code = exams_scores.subject_code)
```

I only get the first score. What should I use if want to get all scores plus their sum.

sample data

```
admission_no       subject     score
1000               Engligh      80
1000               Math         90
1000               Physics      70
2000               English      45
2000               Math         80
2000               Physics      90
```

i am trying to get all marks for a particular admission_no plus the total
so i expect:

admission_no:1000,

score:80,90,70

total:240

Comment: add `group by subject_name` at the end.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: i just added some data

Comment: So you don't want the subject name?

Comment: that i can get i just need the sum for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a roll-up which you can do with a union.

```
SELECT score,subject_name 
 FROM  exams_scores,subjects 
WHERE  (admission_no = 2771) AND(subjects.subject_code = exams_scores.subject_code)
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(score), 'Total'
 FROM  exams_scores
WHERE  (admission_no = 2771)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second query aggregates all your rows to one sum. That is what it should do. 
In order to keep the rows, one way is to add creating the sum in the `select` statement, like this:

```
SELECT 
   score,
   subject_name,
   (SELECT SUM (score) FROM exams_scores,subjects WHERE (admission_no = 2771) AND (subjects.subject_code = exams_scores.subject_code)) AS sum
FROM exams_scores,subjects 
WHERE (admission_no = 2771) AND(subjects.subject_code = exams_scores.subject_code)
```

Like this, the sum is appended to each row.

---

EDIT: In order to add a total row, a `union` statement might do the job:

```
SELECT 
   score,
   subject_name,
   (SELECT SUM (score) FROM exams_scores,subjects WHERE (admission_no = 2771) AND (subjects.subject_code = exams_scores.subject_code)) AS sum
FROM exams_scores,subjects 
WHERE (admission_no = 2771) AND(subjects.subject_code = exams_scores.subject_code)

UNION

SELECT (0, 'Total', (SELECT SUM(... ... ...))
```

This should do it, but I have it not tested in the details. This is only one row at the end, not one row per group.

With `union`, you always need the same number, names and types of columns. Also there might be a point when it is better to leave SQL and use PHP structures in order to add titles, formatting etc.

Comment: I've added to my answer, please see above.

Comment: works after some modification to the union query.thanks again